# python selenium form field iteration

Tags: python, selenium

im trying to iterate through a form to input values for each field.
im using JSON to hold the values and a for loop to iterate through them

When the code is run i get an error message!

error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./fl_bot.py", line 35, in <module>
    ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id="+info+"]")))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

json

```
{
    "billFirstName":"rashawn",
    "billLastName":"doyley",
    "billAddress1":"11612 newburg st",
    "billPostalCode":"11412",
    "billCity":"jamaica",
    "billState":"ny",
    "billHomePhone":"7184139582",
    "billEmailAddress":"rashawndoyley@gmail.com"
}
```

code

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import json
from pprint import pprint

def get_page(model, sku):
    url = "https://www.footlocker.com/product/model:"+str(model)+"/sku:"+ str(sku)+"/"
    return url

data = json.load(open('info.json'))

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

page=browser.get(get_page(277097,"8448001"))

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='pdp_size_select_mask']").click()

shoesize = ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.grid_size:nth-child(8)')))

shoesize.click()

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='pdp_addtocart_button']").click()

browser.get('https://www.footlocker.com/shoppingcart/default.cfm?sku=')

browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#cart_checkout_button').click()



for info , Value in data.items():
    ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id="+info+"]")))

    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id="+info+"]").click()

    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id="+info+"]").clear()
    #print(info,Value)
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id="+info+"]").send_keys(Value)
```

when i use a print statement to print out the elements that are being held in the info variable i get only 4 of the elements and in no particular order

```
billCity
billFirstName
billEmailAddress
billLastName
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./fl_bot.py", line 42, in <module>
    ele = ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 90).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='"+info+"']")))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Comment: Show info.json and error message

Comment: error message is in the top half and the json is added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause is xpath incorrect, need to use single or double quote around id value.

`"//input[@id="+info+"]"` should  be `"//input[@id='"+info+"']"`

Another possible risk is the page take long time to loading after click `CHECKOUT` button,  10 seconds is not enough.  Increase 10 to 60 seconds.

```
for info, value in data.items():
    ele = ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 60)
        .until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='"+info+"']")))

    ele.click()
    ele.clear()
    ele.send_keys(value)
```

Only the first element will wait long time, the next element will take less than 2 seconds to find even you give max find time is 60 seconds, because the page loaded.

Comment: it works partially part of the login form is not being filled in a whole way!

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./fl_bot.py", line 42, in <module>
    ele = ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 90).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='"+info+"']")))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: debug code print out "//input[@id='"+info+"']"  , to see which element not found.

Comment: its only printing these out odly enough billCity
billFirstName
billEmailAddress
billLastName